# How do I group date column headers by quarter, year etc

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel sheet formatted as shown below that has sales data for various products in different locations

[image: Sample table]

How can I create a pivot table that allows me to group the sales data by quarters or years?

There are examples where the date is not a column header but not for my situation

I have tried grouping but that is disabled. I also tried transposing the table so the dates are on the rows but that messes up the data.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the date columns within `Power Query`. Select all date columns and then click `Unpivot Columns` from the `Transform` menu. Rename the resulting `Attribute` column as required.

You can now pivot the resulting table as desired.

***Edit**: if the number of date columns is not fixed, it will be better to select all columns apart from the date columns and choose 'Unpivot Other Columns'*.